# How can I fix Teamviewer sharing when sharer can see your screen but mouse doesn't work?

Tags: teamviewer, desktop-sharing

I am trying to let someone share my screen by using teamviewer. He is able to log on to my machine but he is unable to move the mouse around to actually be able to do anything. Has anyone has this problem in the past or know where I should look to try and solve the problem. I am using ubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score -1):

I have used ubuntu + teamviewer and there was a prompt that appeared whenever I remote accessed it. I had to enable `allow control` or something in that prompt and then `share`

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it another shot and try that. It's appreciated.